# Transform scale in CSS - unexpected change font

Tags: css, scale

My code after hover change style of font. It is probably related to this `font: 14px/1.6 "Open Sans",sans-serif;` but I need this. Is it possible to get this effect (scale to 1.2) in other way? Or change this CSS? My [code](https://jsfiddle.net/27cvjjve/1).

```
.c-data:hover .liczba{
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="u-div">
        <div class="c-data">
            <span class="liczba"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unexpected? And what did you expect? You scale the span, the font changes. Looks like everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this working snippet

```css
body {
  font: 14px/1.6"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.u-div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
}
.c-data {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}
.liczba {
  cursor: default;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 80px;
}
.c-data:hover .liczba {
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-div">
  <div class="c-data">
    <span class="liczba">6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best way to do this :) TY!

Comment: Thank you @Roberto